# Python object as property type

Tags: python, properties

I'm searching for an elegant way to replace setter/getter methodes handling complex data types by properties using the @property decorator.

The class I'm working on should represent some kind of (network) dimmer. It is possible to request/send "resources" addressed by a specific ID to control the device. I'd like to represent those "resources" as properties of my class hiding the request/send mechanism and the cryptical ID numbers. 
Some of those "resources" are just primitive types (int, float, ...) but some are more complex, so I've just created simple classes for them.
This works fine, but there is an ugly source of error: It is not possible to change an attribute of that property directly, I have to set the property completely everytime.

```py
DUMMY_DB = {0x0001: bytearray([0x00])}


class State:
    def __init__(self, on, value):
        self.on = on
        self.value = value

    @staticmethod
    def from_int(val):
        return State(bool(val & 0x80), val & 0x7f)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.on << 7 | self.value


class Dimmer:
    @property
    def state(self) -> State:
        return State.from_int(self._request(0x0001)[0])  # ID 0x0001 => State

    @state.setter
    def state(self, val: State):
        self._send(0x0001, [int(val)])  # ID 0x0001 => State

    # several more properties...

    def _request(self, ident) -> bytearray:
        # usually get resource 'ident' from network/file/...
        return DUMMY_DB[ident]

    def _send(self, ident, value):
        # usually set resource 'ident' on network/file/... using value
        DUMMY_DB[ident] = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dimmer = Dimmer()
    print(dimmer.state.on, dimmer.state.value)  # start state
    dimmer.state.on = True
    dimmer.state.value = 15
    print(dimmer.state.on, dimmer.state.value)  # state did not change
    dimmer.state = State(True, 15)
    print(dimmer.state.on, dimmer.state.value)  # state changed
```

The first print is just to show the start state ("False 0"). But the second print shows that

```py
dimmer.state.on = True
dimmer.state.value = 15
```

are useless. This is because dimmer.state returns a new mutable object which is modified and destroyed without further usage. Only through the complete property assignment the setter methode is called and Dimmer._send invoked.

I think this might be extremely unintuitive and error-prone. Do you have any suggestions for a better design?

Comment: You are always creating a new `State` object. A `Dimmer` should have one `State` fixed to it that will change over time, shouldn't it?

Comment: You are right, but in this case there has to be some kind of (concurrently) mechanism that keeps the internal State object and the real dimmer in sync, which I try to avoid.